# Go - struct not visible in the same package but nested folder

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, go-structtag

I am working on a Go project with the structure as this:

```
pages (folder)
     -> faculty (folder)
        > instructors.go 
        > professors.go

     generalpages.go (inside pages folder)
```

`generalpages.go` handles my `Repository` pattern struct with the following declaration:

```
type Repository struct {
    App *config.AppConfig
}
```

All common pages (eg "Home", "About") works properly having this type of declaration:

```
func (m *Repository) AboutPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 // some functionality
}
```

However, if I want to structure my pages and use the same declaration for my `InstructorsPage` (inside `instructor.go`) as follows, it doesn't work and the error in VSCode says: `undeclared name`.

[image]

My understanding is that an object should be visible within the same package, but still it doesn't work. `go build` is not throwing any error but when I use a routing package (`chi`), it can't reference it correctly.

Comment: folder is not a package always. please specify packages in your file's in first line.

Comment: the compiler will error if the package name is not specified in the first line. of course, the same package name is specified under the same folder.

Comment: The subfolder is a different package.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations `A receiver base type cannot be a pointer or interface type and it must be defined in the same package as the method.`

Answer (score 4):

Go packages do not work that way.

If your directory structure is:

```
moduleRootDir
  parentDir
     subDir
```

and if both directory define the package name `pkg`, then these are two different packages.

If the module name is `module`, then the import path for the package in the parentDir is `module/pkg`, and the package in the subdir is `module/pkg/pkg`. In order to use the names defined in the subDir, import it in the go files in the parentDir:

```
package pkg

import (
   subpkg "module/pkg/pkg"
)
```

Then you can access them  using `subpkg.SymbolName`.